# Async wrapper around public API

Tags: c#, api, http, async-await, wrapper

Tear it apart. I'm mostly concerned around the appropriate use of `ConfigureAwait(false)`, and possible poor handling and duplication of the `HttpClient` in `Invest` and `Get<T>`.

Additionally, I'd also like thoughts on the fact that for usage of these methods, one must call `.Result` to get the actual results. Is this standard for building such a wrapper or is there another way I should achieve this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ProsperAPI
{
    public class ProsperApi
    {
        private readonly string _username;
        private readonly string _password;
        private readonly string _apiBaseUrl = "https://api.prosper.com/v1/";
        private AuthenticationHeaderValue _authenticationHeader;

        #region Constructors

        public ProsperApi(string username, string password)
        {
            _username = username;
            _password = password;
            _authenticationHeader = 
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                    "Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                            string.Format("{0}:{1}", _username, _password))));
        }

        public ProsperApi(string username, string password, string baseUrl) : this(username, password)
        {
            _apiBaseUrl = baseUrl;
        }

        #endregion

        public async Task<bool> Authenticate()
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_username))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("_username", "Credentials are not set");
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_username))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("_password", "Credentials are not set");

            try
            {
                // The account call will fail out if credentials are incorrect, thus
                // we won't spend time getting Notes. If Account information is right,
                // then we load the notes data at the same time, so we can use it 
                await GetAccount().ConfigureAwait(false);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task<List<Note>> GetNotes()
        {
            return await Get<List<Note>>("notes/").ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public async Task<Account> GetAccount()
        {
            return await Get<Account>("account/").ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public async Task<List<Listing>> GetListings()
        {
            return await Get<List<Listing>>("Listings/").ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public async Task<List<Investment>> GetPendingInvestments()
        {
            return await Get<List<Investment>>("Investments/$filter=ListingStatus eq 2").ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public async Task<InvestResponse> Invest(string listingId, string amount)
        {
            using (var client = HttpClientSetup())
            {
                var investment = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("listingId", listingId),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("amount", amount)
                };

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(investment);

                var response = await client.PostAsync("Invest/", content).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    throw new CommunicationException();

                var obj = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InvestResponse>(obj);
            }
        }

        private async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
        {
            using (var client = HttpClientSetup())
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    throw new CommunicationException();

                var obj = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(obj);
            }
        }

        private HttpClient HttpClientSetup()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri(_apiBaseUrl)};
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = _authenticationHeader;

            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Nice first post, "tear it apart" ... lol, that's the spirit! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's something odd about your constructors - normally chained constructors call the constructor with the most parameters, not the other way around:

```
public ProsperApi(string username, string password, string baseUrl) 
    : this(username, password)
```

```
public ProsperApi(string username, string password)
```

Should be:

```
public ProsperApi(string username, string password)
    : this(username, password, null)
```

```
public ProsperApi(string username, string password, string baseUrl)
```

`_apiBaseUrl` will be `null` anyway when you call the 2-parameter constructor. The idea is that you write - and maintain, *one* constructor body.

This would be it:

```
public ProsperApi(string username, string password)
    : this(username, password, null)
{ }

public ProsperApi(string username, string password, string baseUrl) 
{
    _username = username;
    _password = password;
    _apiBaseUrl = baseUrl;

    _authenticationHeader = 
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    string.Format("{0}:{1}", _username, _password))));
}
```

With only 1 constructor doing all the construction work, you don't really need a `#region` here; regions are seldom ever really needed anyway, and more often than not their usage is a smell: if you need to "sectionize" a class, it's likely doing too many things. Now a `Constructors` region is different, it's more like a comment that says what the code already say.

Besides, you can collapse the constructor bodies, leaving only the signatures visible in the IDE; that's possibly more descriptive than any comment you can write there.

---

I like your private fields, `private readonly` fields assigned in the constructor are great. Why isn't `_authenticationHeader` `readonly` as well? If it's only meant to be assigned by the constructor, *and not tampered with*, then it should be made `readonly`.

---

In the `Authenticate` method, your guard clause is a bit weird:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_username))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("_username", "Credentials are not set");
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_username))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("_password", "Credentials are not set");
```

You're not validating the `_password` (you're checking for a null or empty `_username` write) - nice copy+paste error you got here. But nonetheless, the goal of a guard clause is to *fail early*, and with `_username` and `_password` being `readonly` and only assignable in the constructor, wouldn't it make more sense to throw at construction time, if you're going to pass illegal constructor arguments that will make the object fail *later*, might as well throw right away and refuse to create an instance with null/empty credentials.

Other than by the method's name, it's not very clear why `Authenticate` needs `_username` and `_password` to be set, one has to trace all the way down to `HttpClientSetup()` to see `_authenticationHeader` in use, with the actual method call that would probably fail if `_username` or `_password` was null or empty. Preventing null/empty credentials at construction would ensure that the instance is always in a state that allows it to make these calls without worrying about the `username` and `password` values.

You're storing `username` and `password` as private readonly fields, but in reality you don't need to keep either - you only need them to construct the `_authenticationHeader`. I wouldn't keep that data in the instance, it's not needed. I'd change your constructor to this:

```
public ProsperApi(string username, string password, string baseUrl) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Username and password cannot be null or empty.");
    }

    _apiBaseUrl = baseUrl;

    _authenticationHeader = 
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password))));
}
```

Using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` over `string.IsNullOrEmpty` will also refuse to take `"   "` as a valid user name or password.

I went with an `ArgumentException`, because `ArgumentNullException` should be specifically for when an argument is `null` when it shouldn't be - and in this case the argument being null isn't the only way to trip the guard clause, so I'd rather throw a more general exception than a potentially lying/confusing specific exception - there doesn't need to be two separate checks, since the exception message will be the same either way.

---

Lastly, I like how you've named [almost] everything, except the `async` methods should, by convention, be appended with the word `Async` as a suffix, like:

```
public async Task<List<Note>> GetNotesAsync()
public async Task<Account> GetAccountAsync()
public async Task<List<Listing>> GetListingsAsync()
private async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url)
```

Not sure `Get<T>` or `GetAsync<T>` is a very descriptive name though. Perhaps `GetJsonResultAsync<TResult>`?

Answer (score 4):

> I'm mostly concerned around the appropriate use of `ConfigureAwait(false)` …

Your usage is correct. In library code like this, every `await` should use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Though one thing I would do differently are the methods that call `Get`. Instead of:

```
public async Task<List<Note>> GetNotes()
{
    return await Get<List<Note>>("notes/").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

You can write just:

```
public Task<List<Note>> GetNotes()
{
    return Get<List<Note>>("notes/");
}
```

---

> … and possible poor handling and duplication of the `HttpClient` in `Invest` and `Get<T>`.

You could reduce the duplication by creating a helper function like:

```
private async Task<T> GetResponse<T>(
    Func<HttpClient, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> createRequestFunc)
```

Both `Get` and `Invest` would call this method, with the different parts passed in as a lambda.

---

```
var investment = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("listingId", listingId),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("amount", amount)
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(investment);
```

Here, `investment` has to be `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. `Dictionary<string, string>` also implements that interface and since order doesn't matter here and it would make the code simpler, I would use that:

```
var investment = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "listingId", listingId },
    { "amount", amount }
};
```

---

> Additionally, I'd also like thoughts on the fact that for usage of these methods, one must call .Result to get the actual results.

No! To use these methods, one should use `await`. If you're going to use `Result`:

1. You didn't have to bother with `async`, it won't given you any advantage, since `Result` will block a thread.
2. You are likely to get a deadlock if you forgot `ConfigureAwait(false)` somewhere.

Comment: Can you explain your simplification of removing the `async` and `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Why are they unnecessary?

Comment: @Prescott Because that `Task` that's returned by `Get` already behaves exactly the way you want. So you don't need to create another `Task` that `await`s the original one, you can just return the original directly.